# Return an iframe view from a controller function

Tags: php, laravel, iframe

I am new to Laravel. Here is the function I have in SmartpayS controller. I want to return this url in an iframe. 
$url = $item->nodeValue;

```
function processSmartpaySPayment($paymentType = false, $totalAmount = 0, $currency = false, $payingUserId = false, $quoteId = false, $clubMembershipQuotationId = false)
    {
        $callBackUrl = 'smartpays-payment/response/'.$quoteId;

        if (!empty($payingUserId)) {
            $customerDetails = $this->customerRepo->getCustomerDetails($payingUserId);

        } else {
            return false;
        }

        $testString = $this->smartPaySRepo->createSmartpaySPayment($paymentType, env('ENTERPRISE_ID'), 'DE02', 'ECommerce',env('AUTH_TYPE'), $totalAmount, $customerDetails, $currency, $callBackUrl, $quoteId, $clubMembershipQuotationId, env('STORE_RESULT_PAGE') );
        $dom = new \DOMDocument();
        $dom->formatOutput = TRUE;
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
        $dom->loadXml($testString);

        foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('redirectURL') as $item) {

           $url = $item->nodeValue;

        }

        return redirect($url);
}


----------


**********iframe is in the view.(paymentload.blade.php)*************


<iframe src="<?php echo $url; ?>" width="600px" height ="800px" ></iframe>
```

---

I tried to load the iframe. But it says **"Undefined variable: url"**
Help me to return the iframe which is in the View from the controller function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$url = '';
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('redirectURL') as $item) {

  $url = $item->nodeValue;
}

 return redirect($url);
```

i think you are adding **$item->nodeValue** each time so you should use like this

```
$url = '';
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('redirectURL') as $item) {

  $url += $item->nodeValue; // check i have added + here 
}

 return redirect($url);
```

Comment: Thank you. That **Undefined variable: url** issue went off. But, the page redirect to the front page; not the page I want to redirect.
Here is the path the view is available. What should be the route in web.php?

app/Modules/Payment/Resources/Views/smartpay/paymentload.blade.php

Comment: just put `dd($url)` before return and show what you are getting ?